# Computer crashed aconnect now lists Timidity service that isn't active on port 128:0

Tags: mint, midi, dosbox

I was playing a game in Dosbox (Daggerfall to be exact) and my computer froze and I had to force restart. When I started Timidity service again using "Timidity -iAD" the service started on port 129:0 rather than 128:0.
So, I typed "aconnect -o" in console and the output was as followed:

```
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 128: 'TiMidity' [type=user]
    0 'TiMidity port 0 '
    1 'TiMidity port 1 '
    2 'TiMidity port 2 '
    3 'TiMidity port 3 '
client 129: 'TiMidity' [type=user]
    0 'TiMidity port 0 '
    1 'TiMidity port 1 '
    2 'TiMidity port 2 '
    3 'TiMidity port 3 '
```

Quiting Timidity only removes client 129. Music no longer works in Dosbox, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by uninstalling Timidity and Freepats.

Comment: Apparently, somebody decided to start Timidity automatically (which would be useful, if you wanted it). Does Mint have systemd integration for Timidity?